# Find file with largest number in filename in each sub-directory with python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, max

I am trying to find the file with the largest number in the filename in each subdirectory. This is so I can acomplish opening the most recent file in each subdirectory.  Each file will follow the naming convetion of date filename.xlsx.

Ex. 20180620 file name.xlsx

I have a code that works for searching one directory for largest numbers.

```
dirname = py.path.local(path)

list_of_files = []

for file in dirname.visit(fil='*.xlsx', bf=True):
    list_of_files.append(file)

largest = max(list_of_files)
print (largest)
```

I am pretty new to Python and I can't quite figure out how to make this style of code work looking for the file with the largest number in each subdirectory within a directory. I have tried many variations off of this following code, but I can't get it to print out just the file with the largest number from each subdirectory.

```
list_of_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".xlsx")):
            list_of_files.append(files)
            largest = max(list_of_files)
            print (largest)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please clarify your question? What do you mean "largest number"? Do you mean the content of the file? A number inside an excel workbook? Do you mean the filename itself?

Comment: No problem.  I am tyring to open the newest file by date.  The date will be in the filename with the same format for each subdirectory.  date file name.xlsx.  ex. 20180620 file name.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code block does *almost* what you want to do, you've just nested your operations incorrectly.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    # new subdir, so let's make a new...
    list_of_files = []
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".xlsx")):
            list_of_files.append(name)  # you originally appended the list of all names!
    # once we're here, list_of_files has all the filenames in it,
    # so we can find the largest and print it
    largest = max(list_of_files)
    print (largest)
```

If I can suggest a shorter solution:

```
[(root, max(fname for fname in files if fname.endswith(".xlsx"))) for
 root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)]
```

This will give you a list of `(dirname, largest_filename)` pairs, rather than just printing them to the screen.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems much closer than I was before.  When I use the top code as written, it says "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence".  Right now, I am testing with three subdirectories inside of the parent directory that I have the path pointed to.  I am anticipating that it will return 3 files from the print statement, then; the filename with the highest number from each subdirectory.  The bottom code produced the same ValueEerror message.

Comment: @Philalethes then it seems likely that you've pointed the code at the wrong path. Try printing every file from there as a debug method? (inside `for name in files` but before `if name.endswith(".xlsx")` write: `print("{}/{}".format(root, name))`)

Comment: Thanks, again for the followup.  I had tried printing the list in a few spots too, and I can see the files.  If I run upto your debugging line, I can see the list of all the files in all the subdirectories.  As soon as I try to run the code through to the largest - max() line and print (largest) line it gives me the "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence".  If I nest the largest variable and the print (largest) lines all the way to the left, it will print the largest filename of the final directory.  Everywhere else I put these two lines of code, it is giving me the ValueError.

Comment: @Philalethes your problem appears to be unrelated to the code now (or else it's a typo that's not apparent) so I'm not sure how else I can help you. The error message you're receiving is self-descriptive, so you'll have to discover why `list_of_files` appears to be empty when you call `max` on it. Good luck!

Comment: I fired up pycharm (which I am not very adept at) and tried to watch what was happening as I stepped through the funciton.  The strange thing to me was the code skipped right over the if file.endswith("xlsx").  I initially did not have a file in the parent directory, just three subdirectories.  As soon as I put a file in the parent directory too, the code started to work!  It spit out the one file in the parent directory as the max (it was the only file) and then it stepped through the other subdirectories.  Any ideas why having a file in the parent directory would matter?